# My hashmap is not getting implemented in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using this hashmap to transfer the username from one child(Users) to another(Notes) in database.

In my app you can create as well as update notes.

I want that every time a note is created or updated in the database a username is added along with the note. the username is saved in the users child.

But when the note is created the username doesn't show up. But when the note is updated, it is added in the child.

here is the code:

```
fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("Notes").child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
current_user_id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    String title = etTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String content = etContent.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
      createNote(title, content);
      putUsername();
    } else {
      Snackbar.make(view, "Fill empty fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
});

private void putUsername() {
  UsersRef.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      String username = snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
      HashMap usernameMap = new HashMap();
      usernameMap.put("username", username);
      fNotesDatabase.child(noteID).updateChildren(usernameMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
  });
}
```

I'm not able to understand as how come the username is added when the note is updated but not when the note us created.

[image: My database]

I have updated the second note thats why there is a username but when is simply created the upper one there username is not showing.

**EDIT**

putData method :

```
     private void putData() {

    if (isExist) {
        fNotesDatabase.child(noteID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("title") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("content")) {
                    String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                    String content = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue().toString();

                    etTitle.setText(title);
                    etContent.setText(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

createNote method:

```
     private void createNote(String title, String content) {

    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        Calendar calFordDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calFordDate.getTime());


        if (isExist) {
            Map updateMap = new HashMap();
            updateMap.put("title", etTitle.getText().toString().trim());
            updateMap.put("content", etContent.getText().toString().trim());
            updateMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            updateMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);

            fNotesDatabase.child(noteID).updateChildren(updateMap);

            SendUsersToPostActivity();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Article updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            final DatabaseReference newNoteRef = fNotesDatabase.push();

            final Map noteMap = new HashMap();
            noteMap.put("title", title);
            noteMap.put("content", content);
            noteMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            noteMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);

            Thread mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    newNoteRef.setValue(noteMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewNoteActivity.this, "Article Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                SendUsersToPostActivity();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(NewNoteActivity.this, "ERROR: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            mainThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the user name into the call to `createNote` and write it to the note at the same time you write the title and content?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen createNote is based on child(Notes). but this username is originally saved in child(Users). so i want to import it from Users to Notes when the note is created.

Comment: Sounds possible. Can you edit your question to show what `createNote` looks like? Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have have added the edits.. if possible please take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain, but I don't see where you set the `noteID` value that `putUsername` depends on.

In general though, I'd recommend changing `createNote` to take all the data that it needs for the new note, including the user name:

```
btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    String title = etTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String content = etContent.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(content) && fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
      UsersRef.child(current_user_id).child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          String username = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

          createNote(title, content, current_user_id, username);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
          throw error.toException()
        }
      });
    } else {
      Snackbar.make(view, "Fill empty fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
});

private void createNote(String title, String content, String uid, String username) {
    Calendar calFordDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calFordDate.getTime());

    Map updateMap = new HashMap();
    updateMap.put("title", title);
    updateMap.put("content", content);
    updateMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    updateMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);
    updateMap.put("uid",uid);
    updateMap.put("username",username);

    final DatabaseReference noteRef = isExist ? fNotesDatabase.push() : fNotesDatabase.child(noteID);

    noteRef.updateChildren(noteMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(NewNoteActivity.this, "Article "+(isExists ? "updated" : "created"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SendUsersToPostActivity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewNoteActivity.this, "ERROR: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Some of the changes in this code versus yours:

- Looks up the user name before creating the new note. Uses a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` for this, to ensure we only do this once for every button click.
- Only loads the `username` child of the user profile, since that's all you use.
- Use the values you pass into `createNote` instead of recalculating them from the UI views.
- Only has a single write to the database, as `updateChildren` works fine for creating the initial data too.
- There is no need to run the Firebase `setValue` call on a new thread, as Firebase runs it off the main thread already.
- Please don't leave `onCancelled` empty, as it may hide important error messages.

Comment: thanks for putting in such efforts....  But now I'm getting FATAL error 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() ' AT '   final DatabaseReference noteRef = isExist ? fNotesDatabase.push() : fNotesDatabase.child(noteID);  ' and at '    createNote(title, content, current_user_id, username); ' and at '  public class NewNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  '

Comment: That sounds like `noteID` is empty. I haven't done anything to that though, so it's coming in that way from your code.

Comment: Also when updating, it is creating a new note instead of updating the previous.

Comment: But to check 'noteId' i have this method '  try {
            noteID = getIntent().getStringExtra("noteId");

            if (!noteID.trim().equals("")) {
                isExist = true;
            } else {
                isExist = false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }'

Comment: "Also when updating, it is creating a new note instead of updating the previous." that once again seems to indicate that your `noteID` is not being set, which is something that I changed nothing about in my answer.

Comment: oh... Could you please tell me whats wrong with the method i have already used for noteID ? thanks..

Comment: I'm utterly grateful of you for helping me... Thanks